# Can SqlAlchemy's array_agg function accept more than one column?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to return arrays with data from the entire row (so all columns), not just a single column. I can do this with a raw sql statement in Postgresql,

```sql
SELECT 
     array_agg(users.*) 
FROM users 
WHERE 
     l_name LIKE 'Br%' 
GROUP BY f_name;
```

but when I try to do it with SqlAlchemy, I'm getting

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'InstrumentedAttribute'

For example, when I execute this query, it works fine

```py
query: Query[User] = session.query(array_agg(self.user.f_name))
```

But with this I get arrays of rows with only one column value in them (in this example, the first name of a user) whereas I want the entire row (all columns for a user).

I've tried explicitly listing multiple columns, but to no avail. For example I've tried this:

```py
query: Query[User] = session.query(array_agg((self.user.f_name, self.user.l_name))))
```

But it doesn't work. I get the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python feature unpack for create

```
example = [func.array_agg(column) for column in self.example.__table__.columns]
query = self.dbsession.query(*attach)
```

And after join results